# Angular directive behaviour not expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive `

```
var xmlToHtml = function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: 'Components/XML2Html/views/XML2Html.html',
        controllerAs: 'XmlToHtmlController',
        bindToController: true,
        scope: {
            xslt: '@',
            administrator: '='
        },
        link: function () {
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $timeout, $sce, $http, $filter, $timeout, $window) {
            $scope.administrator = this.administrator;
            $scope.$watch('administrator', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                console.log($scope.administrator);
            }, true);
        },
    };
}
xmlToHtml.$inject = [];
```

and in my html

```
 <div xml-to-html xslt="test.xslt" administrator="Agent.Administrator"></div>
```

scope Agent.Administrator is boolean. And change value outside of directive, so i want two ways binding.

The problem is that is not working, if bool administrator change value, directive know nothing! But the strange is that if i replace 'Agent.Administrator' with 'Agent' (all object and not only one flag of this) working perfect and catch any change of flag 'Administrator'.

Is there any different approach for boolean in directives?
The strange here is that if i pass only the flag, directive doesn't know any of changes, but if i pass all object, directive know any changes.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `boolean` is a primitive type, so when you pass a `boolean` it copies the value and you have a new item. You can pass a object `Administrator` which has a property with that boolean value, example

```
Agent.Administrator = { isAdmin: false };
```

Comment: but in my directive i have   
scope: {
            xslt: '@',
            administrator: '='
        }, the symbol '=' means that not creating copy but two ways of communicative

Comment: @GomuGomuNoRocket `Administrator` , must be an object, e.g. Agent.Administrator otherwise you won't get a proper reference to update the parent scope

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put

```
 Agent.Administrator=true;
```